# Is there a way to separate Java annotation processing errors from other compilation errors?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac, annotation-processing

I have a maven module with 1000+ Java source files. Some of these have annotations that are processed via processors Dagger and Immutables, each of which generates code. When I have an error in a Dagger or Immutables annotated file, the annotation processor fails to complete. The resulting build errors contain the "real" error that triggered the processor to fail, as well as lots of errors complaining about not being able to find the generated code, e.g. 137 errors in my current example. Browsing all such errors to find the "real" error is tedious.

Is there a way to separate the annotation-processing error from the other errors that result from it failing to generate code?

I have tried both `proc:none` and `proc:only` as `javac` arguments, but neither seems to make any difference.

In case it helps, here is the part of pom.xml for compilation

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-proc:only</arg>
                        <arg>-verbose</arg>
                        <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
                        <arg>1000</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have tried with and without `-proc:only` and `-proc:none`. Note that the `-Xmaxerrs 1000` is needed as the default seems to be 100, for me at least.

Comment: Do you mean one file annotated with Dagger/Immutables contains an error that makes the file not compilable (for example a missing semi-column) and that makes the processor fail? Annotation processing kicks over processing rounds, the first round is usually a pure Java code compilation and once that's done, then annotation processing kicks into a new compilation round. Can you show what your build file looks like (e.g. pom.xml if you use Maven)?

Comment: Something like that. It varies. In this particular case I think it was some dependency that had not been refreshed, causing some Dagger/Immutables-annotated file to fail to compile, which then in turn caused lots of other files that depended on it to fail to compile.

Comment: I don't think you can really do much except for filtering the errors on some specific text. The issue is that you're already in the Dagger compilation round, so the control of logging the error messages for the compiler is not owned by you until when the annotation processor is over. Specifically, once Dagger's processor is called to process its supported annotations, it will start to process them (eventually logging errors) and then the compiler will recompile everything again, without knowing whether it's compiling source files or generated files.

Answer (score 0):

Till I get a better answer (if one is possible) my strategy so far (as suggested by "@Matteo NNZ") is to output the build log to a file and then exclude the most common issue resulting from failing to generate code "cannot find symbol", e.g.

```
$ grep "^\[ERROR\] /" output.txt | grep -v "cannot find symbol"
```

Note that setting something like `-Xmaxerrs 1000` is critical here to ensure the "real" error is not missed.

Comment: FYI, when an annotation processor is declared in the compiler path, it will be called by the compiler to process the annotations. When these annotations are processed, if something goes wrong, the annotation processor will log an error through the ProcessorLogger which is passed by the compiler and that is the same that the standard compiler uses to log errors. Hence, there is simply no way to determine whether an error message has been logged by the main compiler (which is what you're interested into) or the processor (which uses the same logger), except if the processor marks the messages.

Comment: I've worked on some annotation processors and I usually add a standard prefix to each error message (e.g. [my-processor] ... ). But that's doable when you own the annotation processor, which is not the case for Dagger/Immutables. In that case, you can only rely on the good practice of external developers.